# @SpringBootTest requiring database connection?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, testcontainers

I have some integration tests, for which I am using Testcontainers. But I have suddenly realized that when my docker container with database for my application is down, all the other tests (excluding the integration tests using Testcontainers) are failing (even the `contextLoads()` test generated by Spring Boot initializr)

I get:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext    at
> org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132)
>
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
> Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path
> resource
>
> [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]:
> Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
> liquibase.exception.DatabaseException:
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications
> link failure

It is obvious that the application wants to connect to the database, and the database container is down.

I've been investigating, but I don't remember ever needing to start a container just for the test/build process of an application, so this problem is new for me. But if there is something done wrong, it could be here, in my `AbstractDatabaseIT` class:

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = AbstractDatabaseIT.DockerMySqlDataSourceInitializer.class)
@Testcontainers
public abstract class AbstractDatabaseIT {

    private static final String MYSQL_IMAGE_NAME = "mysql:5.7.24";

    public static final MySQLContainer<?> mySQLContainer = new MySQLContainer<>(MYSQL_IMAGE_NAME);

    static {
        mySQLContainer.start();
    }

    public static class DockerMySqlDataSourceInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {

        @Override
        public void initialize(@NotNull ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {

            Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
            parameters.put("command", "--character-set-server=utf8");
            TestPropertySourceUtils.addInlinedPropertiesToEnvironment(
                    applicationContext,
                    "spring.datasource.url=" + mySQLContainer.getJdbcUrl(),
                    "spring.datasource.username=" + mySQLContainer.getUsername(),
                    "spring.datasource.password=" + mySQLContainer.getPassword()
            );
            mySQLContainer.setParameters(parameters);
        }
    }

}
```

The integration test extend this class:

```
public class ChallengeIT extends AbstractDatabaseIT {

    @Autowired
    private ChallengeRepository repository;

    // tests here
```

All the other, non-integration classes have `@SpringBootTest` annotation, and the dependencies injected using @Autowired (maybe this is a problem here?)

```
@SpringBootTest
class EthMessageVerifierTest {

    @Autowired
    private EthMessageVerifier ethMessageVerifier;

    // tests here
```

What am I missing here? I remember seeing the H2 database dependency all around many projects. Should I drop the testcontainers in favour of H2? Or can I somehow create a single testcontainer instance for all the other tests?

Answer (score 5):

Tests that you annotate with `@SpringBootTest` try to populate the entire Spring context. This includes all your beans: your web layer, your business logic, your database setup, etc.

Hence all the infrastructure (e.g. messaging queues, remote systems, databases) that you need otherwise to run your entire application also needs to be present for such tests.

So `@SpringBootTest` also indicates an integration test and you need to provide your database setup as on application start, Spring Boot's auto-configuration tries to configure your `DataSource`.

For more information, consider this [article on @SpringBootTest](https://rieckpil.de/guide-to-springboottest-for-spring-boot-integration-tests/) and this general [overview about unit & integration testing with Spring Boot](https://rieckpil.de/spring-boot-unit-and-integration-testing-overview/). You don't always have to use `@SpringBootTest` and can also use one of S[pring Boots many test slice annotations](https://rieckpil.de/spring-boot-test-slices-overview-and-usage/) to test something in isolation.